# How would you get a list of best sellers from Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

I'm working on Spree 2.3.1 and I've been trying to get a list of "best sellers" based on qty for 2 days...any ideas?

So far I've tried to come up with a query using ActiveRecords helpers which I'm pretty new at:

```
Spree::Product.includes(variants: {line_items: :order}).group('spree_products.id')
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Seems like this would be something available out of the box.

Comment: SELECT SUM(quantity), variant_id FROM "spree_line_items" INNER JOIN
spree_orders ON spree_orders.id = spree_line_items.order_id WHERE
spree_orders.state = 'complete' GROUP BY variant_id;

Answer (score 4):

This gem seems to do what you are looking for https://github.com/sylvinho81/spree_best_sellers

I extracted the query from the code and this is what gets a list of products in order of how many have been sold.

```
Spree::Product.active.select("spree_products.*, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as total_qty, spree_line_items.variant_id").
    joins(:line_items).joins("INNER JOIN spree_orders ON spree_orders.id = spree_line_items.order_id").
    where("spree_orders.state = 'complete'").
    group("spree_line_items.variant_id, spree_products.id").order("total_qty DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that I would use:

Step 1 - SQL/Rails query

As suggested by Sumeet in his comment. I would expand the query to limit the Orders by date.

- easy to implement.
- very heavy on the database.

Use it only if you need it for e.g.: Admin Panel that is rarely being viewed or the site itself is not so popular.

Step 2 - Expand the functionality by adding task to update the product position in the Taxon

If you would like to provide a bestselling view for the frontend User on a site that has a lot of Users it wouldn't be a good idea to perform heavy counting SQL operations every time User displays product list. Instead, you could make a use of the existing position field that Products have in the relation to the Taxons, perform the query from the previous point and update the positions accordingly. You could trigger the position update also after each Order in the scope of the Taxons that line items belong to.

Comment: This is a frontend solution so I'll keep that in mind. I ended up writing raw sql but I used an alias to capture the sum i.e. sum(line_items.quantity) as total_qty. However, I kept getting an error saying that products does not have a total_qty attribute but doing the same query with raw sql worked. Go figure!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the query that Qwertie provided you. Instead of doing that you can add the gem in you Gemfile and use it in your code:

> gem "spree_best_sellers", :git =>
>   "https://github.com/sylvinho81/spree_best_sellers.git", :branch =>
>   '3-0-stable'

Since you are using Spree 2.3.1, you will need to adapt the gem.